# How to distribute Beam Tasks evenly on Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I have a simple pipeline that reads records both both a text file and mysql and tries to reconcile them, i.e. insert records when they don't exist in the DB, update records in the DB with the file, and do some other updates to records in the DB that do not exist in the file.

A problem that arises when run with 2M records in Spark is the following:

[image]

My hunch is that the following code is producing that imbalance

```
        final TupleTag<FileRecord> fileTag = new TupleTag<>();
        final TupleTag<MysqlRecord> mysqlTag = new TupleTag<>();
        PCollection<KV<Integer, CoGbkResult>> joinedRawCollection =
                KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(fileTag, fileRecords)
                        .and(mysqlTag, mysqlRecords)
                        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create());
```

Here is the Spark Executor DAG visualization

[image]

Eventually the one worker will run out of memory. I know in Spark natively, one can specify Partitioners to help distribute the workload across workers. However, how do I do that in Beam?

**EDIT:**

I suspected that JDBCIo couldn't properly distribute the one query so I split it up into multiple PCollections and then flattened them later. I read much faster from Mysql, but eventually ran into the same problem.

Here are the stages that are being worked on:
[image]

But each stage still suffers from that imbalance?:
[image]

Comment: Actually it might look like the reason for this imbalance is because it's the read step from MySQL with that many records. Since JDBCIO presumably does not distribute the one SELECT query, we see that contention. Let me try to split it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question with the realization of my own failure to differentiate between Spark Stages and task. The tasks were indeed spread out, I just actually did not allocate enough memory to the driver program.